# Is it possible to call a function in a shared library that has not been declared?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, gnu, readline

The short version:
I'm trying to use a function in a shared library that hasn't been declared in a header file. Is it possible? If so, how?

The long version:
I'm trying to use GNU readline-7.0 as a shared library. Unfortunately it will echo input by default unless you turn it off with an api call. Sadly this api call wasn't declared in their header, because someone forgot. [see details here](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-readline@gnu.org/msg01174.html) Note: I can't update to a newer readline, so I'm stuck with this library. How do I use this undeclared function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the linked bug, there is no external declaration in the header file even though the function exists in the implementation.

The link also shows the fix with the added declaration:

```
extern int rl_tty_set_echoing PARAMS((int));
```

So you can add this in your code right after `#include <readline.h>`

Comment: Already tried that. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though...

....: In function `main':
....: undefined reference to `rl_tty_set_echoing(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
E    [LINKCXX] (myapp#myprog) c2s_ssh_sink: command exited with return code 1
make-4.2.1[1]: *** [//amake.m.module:617: //myapp/myprog] Error 1
E       [core] make failed with exit code 2

Comment: Oh, you're using C++. (Please tell us that next time.) Try `extern "C" int rl_tty_set_echoing(int);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is *yes*!!!

Just use the library `-ldl` with function `dlopen(3)`, etc.  This library allows you to load a shared object and search for identifiers that you know nothing about.  Of course, the static typing nature of C forces to declare the interface of those functions with a prototype, so once you get a `(void *)` to the object you can cast it to something like `int (*t)()` and jump to it with a `t();` call.

In the manual page you will get the details, dlopen allows you to search a shared object for symbols passed as strings.  It returns pointers to the places those identifiers have been loaded in memory.  You can even do this with your own program.

On the other hand, this is a feature of ELF shared loaded modules.  If you are running a.out executables or otherwise, it is now waranteed that you'll have a `dlopen(3)` library for it, or that it will work that way.